# Decay of positive definite functions in Lp

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous positive-definite function with $f(0)=1$. Positive-definiteness of $f$ means
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(x_i-x_j)y_i y_j \geq 0
$$
for all $n\geq 1, x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Question.** If $f \in L^{p}$ for some $p>2$, must we have $f(x)=O(|x|^{-c})$ for some $c>0$?

Note that, by Bochner's theorem, $f = \widehat{\mu}$ for some probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Context: This is a natural extension of this question: [$L^p$ implies polynomial decay?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296804/lp-implies-polynomial-decay)

I am posting this over at MO, since it has stood several months here with no progress. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278988/decay-of-positive-definite-function-in-lp

Comment: It's been a while since I read up on them, but if I recall correctly, the maximum value is attained at 0, right?

Comment: @CameronWilliams That's true.

Comment: The question was answered [at Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278988/decay-of-positive-definite-function-in-lp).